# Does the HTTP request header Sec-Fetch-Mode value "navigate" indicate top-level navigation used in SameSite cookie policy?

Tags: http, cookies, http-headers, xss, samesite

Background: I'm working on an application where I'm looking into further restricting my cross-site cookies by modifying the default value for `SameSite` on my cookies.  Before I make the change, I'm investigating to get a better sense of which requests will be affected by a change from `Lax` to `Strict`.

Per [XS-Leaks](https://xsleaks.dev/docs/defenses/opt-in/same-site-cookies/):

> The only difference between `Lax` and `Strict` is that `Lax` mode allows cookies to be added to requests triggered by cross-site top-level navigations. This makes `Lax` cookies much easier to deploy since they won’t break incoming links to your application.

(See also: [this RFC draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis#name-top-level-navigations))

To narrow down the relevant requests in my logs, I'm looking at requests that have the `Sec-Fetch-Site` header set to `cross-site`.  I'm wondering if I can also get a sense of which interactions involve top-level navigation by looking at the `Sec-Fetch-Mode` header.  Does the `navigation` value for that header correspond exactly to the definition of top-level navigation for the purpose of sending `SameSite Lax` cookies?

Comment: No. `Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate` is also used with a navigation request _within_ an iframe, which is therefore not top-level.